# How to limit localhost to local browsers?

Tags: server, webserver, localhost

I have created a C++ server for a local use.

It does not have authentication system.

The problem is other computers can easily connect to this server by my IP and port.

How can I limit this server to only my local browsers.

Comment: When you are binding the port for the service just specify the interface IP as: `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @AmeyaVS You made a comment. Make an answer.

Comment: @jdwolf submitted an answer. Let me know in-case it requires more information or references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are binding the port for the service just specify the interface IP as: `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508685/understanding-inaddr-any-for-socket-programming) is a reference about the `INADDR_ANY`.

Without sample code I am guessing that you have bound the interface with `INADDR_ANY`.